# Can GeoWebCache serve tiles from blobstore?

Tags: tiles, geowebcache, proxy, mapproxy

Currently I use MapProxy to serve custom sqlite tile stores with a certain schema.  I would like to enable GeoWebCache to do the same, but I don't know if GWC work the same way that mapproxy does.

MapProxy will serve out all the data in my cache if it exists.  Since I have no source for this cache, if there is a missing tile, there is no server to retrieve it and nothing is shown for that tile.

I see that GeoWebCache has no native sqlite blobstore and the one github fork that added sqlite as a blob store is no longer available.  Since GWC works by pointing it to a map service which it will then tile, will it serve requests for data from the cache even if that source is down?

I eventually want to get to the point where GWC is serving out sqlite tiles as it's own service and not reliant on another map service source.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, GWC will continue to serve cached tiles even if the WMS it's proxying is not available.  It will fail rather than proceeding with the old data if the cached tile has expired though.